# Cannot locate rosdep definition for [joint_state_publisher]

Tags: rosdep, joint-state-publisher, ros-groovy, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of my packages has a run dependency on the joint state publisher (cfrom a roslauncher). Checking the dependencies with rosdep gives me this error:

```
$ rosdep check robosem_meta
All system dependencies have been satisified
ERROR[robosem_meta]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [joint_state_publisher]
        rosdep key : joint_state_publisher
        OS name    : ubuntu
        OS version : precise
        Data: <no data>
```

I have the joint_state_publisher installed and I can use it without problems. So this is not a real problem, but I would still like to fix it. Anyone knows how?

PS: Unfortunately the link for filing issue tickets on the wiki is not [existent](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_state_publisher) or [broken](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_model_visualization), otherwise I would have used that for problems like this one here. Maybe the maintainer could move the code to Github or Bitbucket?

**/edit:** My package is a catkin package and the dependency on the joint_state_publisher is defined like this:

```
<run_depend>joint_state_publisher</run_depend>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63302/cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Bjoint_state_publisher%5D/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobotacm](https://answers.ros.org/users/4956/sobotacm/) on 2013-05-23**:
What happens when you do "rosdep install joint_state_publisher"?

You could try installing urdf_tools from http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf_tools/ which comes with the joint_state_publisher node.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-05-23**:
@sobotacm The joint_state_publisher is installed and working. The only issue is that rosdep does not recognise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to:

http://ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html

`joint_state_publisher` is part of the `robot_model_visualization` stack which is dry (`rosbuild`).  `caktin` packages cannot depend on `rosbuild` packages.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-05-23**:
So that's the reason why rosdep complains?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-23**:
Yes. Since catkin can't resolve it, the dependency is passed along to rosdep. That has some advantages, but frequently generates confusing error messages.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-23**:
@joq is correct. All catkin dependencies are passed to rosdep for processing. rosdep has no knowledge of dry (rosbuild) packages so when you list a dry package as a dependency of a wet package, rosdep doesn't know what to do with it.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-05-23**:
Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `manifest.xml`, you probably have the following line:

```
<rosdep name="joint_state_publisher"/>
```

This is incorrect; instead, change it to:

```
<depend package="joint_state_publisher"/>
```

The reason is that `rosdep` checks for *system* dependencies (i.e., non-ROS software that is available as a debian package, like `libmesa` or `qt4-qmake`). On the other hand, `rospack` (which is invoked by the `depend` tag) is responsible for finding *ROS package* dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-05-23**:
I forgot to mention, that my package is a catkin package and the dependency is defined as   `<run_depend>joint_state_publisher</run_depend>`. I have added this information to my question. Any idea what could cause this error in a catkin package?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-05-23**:
All right, I assumed you were using rosbuild. William's answer is correct.